# Cpu overheat for no reason

Tags: cpu

I have AMD fx-4100 quad-core with windows 10 LTSC 2019 X64 and with Comodo internet security with the last update.
I play call of duty mobile with a game loop emulator and my maximum CPU temperature is 60°C on the game and on normal use, it was 40-44°C. but after I installed the ping tester and net-tools 5 and LOIC for my school homework(ethical hacking), my CPU on the game is going to 70°C and in normal use even if i don't do anything with it the temperature keep going up until 57°C-60°C
I uninstalled them but still, nothing changed. I've done these steps, but it didn't help

- checked my task manager
- run games on low graphic
- undo my overclock
- update my Drivers
- scan my pc for malware
- stop unnecessary programs and services
- clean my PC's fan and case and change the thermal grease
- add an extra fan
- reinstall my windows 10

Comment: What model of cooler do you use?

Comment: Amd stock fan 4000 rpm Max , 3 pin

Comment: 70° does not qualify as 'overheating'. ProcHot on most CPUs these days is around 100°.

Comment: Yes but my cpu is old
Iknow its ok to reach the 70C but i never seen that temperature before
 something is causing this

Comment: Even my ancient i7 4790 is OK up to 75 C.

Comment: (ping tester and net-tools 5 and LOIC), we have no idea, what software you a referring to, clarification might help

Comment: This programs used to gather information (ping tester - net tools 5 )and attack the target (LOIC)  ,(im learning thr ethical hack in the school)

Answer (score 0):

First you should determine whether this is a hardware or software issue. Try booting your computer from a [Live CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD), use it for a while, and see if the problem persists. If the overheating still occurs, you have a hardware issue. If the problem goes away, you have a software issue in your OS environment.

If the hardware issue persists, make sure you're not overlooking environmental factors such as blocking of vents, placement of the computer near a heat source or in direct sunlight, or the arrival of warmer weather. You can check the contact between your CPU and heat sink, and the proper operation of fans and blowers in the computer chassis. And you can try resetting your BIOS to factory settings, since the BIOS likely has responsibility for sensing temperature and regulating fan speeds.

If this is a software issue, the troubleshooting possibilities are beyond the scope of this question. You may have contracted a malicious program which is hiding from your diagnostic tools, or the OS may be malfunctioning in some subtle way. The most reliable solution would be to back up your personal data and reinstall your OS from scratch.